# Текстурные координаты в OpenGL

Tags: delphi, opengl

Я пытаюсь наложить текстуру на прямоугольник с помощью шейдера. Текстура загружена, передается на обработку в шейдер через стандартную переменную следующим образом

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Textures[Param0].Num);
```

Данные о текстурных координатах передаю атрибутом вместе с данными о вершинах и цвете

```
...
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, SizeOf(TVertex), Pointer(SizeOf(Single)*6));
```

Сами текстурные координаты записываю в массив данных для каждой вершины прямоугольника

```
Vertexes[0] := Vertex(X1, Y1, FAKE_FRGBA, routRPoint(0, 1));
Vertexes[1] := Vertex(X2, Y1, FAKE_FRGBA, routRPoint(1, 1));
Vertexes[2] := Vertex(X2, Y2, FAKE_FRGBA, routRPoint(1, 0));
Vertexes[3] := Vertex(X1, Y2, FAKE_FRGBA, routRPoint(0, 0));
```

Здесь функция `routRPoint(0, 1)` возвращает переменную-запись с двумя параметрами типа `Single`.

Вершинный шейдер

```
layout(location = 0) in vec2 Position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 InColor;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 TexCoord;
out vec2 Coord;
out vec4 Color;
void main() {
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    gl_FrontColor = InColor;
    Color = InColor;
    Coord = TexCoord;
}
```

Фрагментный шейдер

```
in vec2 Coord;
in vec4 Color;
uniform sampler2D texture0;
void main() {
    if (Color == vec4(0,0,0,0)){
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture0, Coord);
    }
    else{
        gl_FragColor = Color;
    };
}
```

Инициализируя `OpenGL`, указываю настройки области вывода:

```
glOrtho(0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, 0, -1, 1);
glViewPort(0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);
```

В итоге текстура накладывается неправильно.

Текущий вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как должно было вывестись:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Займитесь отладкой.

Что надо попробовать и проверить:

- убедитесь, что текстурные координаты верны. Сделайте `gl_FragColor = vec4(Coord.x, Coord.y, 0.0, 1.0);`. Цвет квадрата должен получится с градиентом от черного к красному и зеленому (по соответствующим осям).
- убедитесь, что сама текструа загружена верно. Сделайте передачу позиции во фрагментный шейдер и `gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture0, Position / 100.0 + vec2(0.0, 0.0));` (подберите масштаб и смещение, чтобы увидеть всю текстуру). Текстура должна показаться полностью.
- проверьте, что режим повторения текстуры (желательно всегда использовать `GL_REPEAT`) совпадает с используемым диапазоном UV.

Comment: Спасибо за советы по отладке. Благодаря методу отладки текстурных координат, который вы предложили, мне удалось найти ошибку, связанную с типом данных. Я использовал функцию, которая возвращала числа с типом `Real`, а в шейдере необходимо было использовать тип `Single`.